# Adding a Web Services interface to Flash Media Server and integrate with .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, flash-media-server

I like to capture videos on webcams and stream them through RTMP protocol to my viewers.

to achieve this I use flash media server.

But I have this issue, how to stream video from webcam to FMS in .NET

Is it possible to integrate FMS (Flash Media Server) to .Net?

Comment: FYI, it's just ".NET", not "dotNet".

Comment: try this http://www.fluorinefx.com/